# How are shares of private corporations valued for the purpose of income tax?

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, gift-tax

If somebody gives me stock in a private corporation, how is that gift valued for the purposes of income tax? Assume the stock is unlisted and has no publicly tradable value.

I know that all stocks have a "par value" but usually for a private corporation that par value is nominal.

Comment: Do you really mean _gift_ tax, as your question is tagged?  In the USA that is owed by the giver, not you (the recipient).  For future _income_ tax purposes, if the stock has appreciated between the giver's acquisition and the time of gift--as would be typical--you (the recipient) receive the giver's basis and the exact value at the time of gift is not relevant.

Comment: @perimpossible Here is a scenario. Imagine if Ned Johnson, owner of Fidelity Investments, a private company worth billions of dollars gives 20% of the company as a gift to his daughter Abigail. Assume Fidelity stock is not traded, so it has no easily ascertainable specific value. How is that gift treated from a tax point of view?

Comment: The receiver of a gift never pays income tax on it, whether it's a private company, a public company, a famous painting, or anything else (including cash). For very valuable gifts, the _giver_ may be responsible to pay a gift tax.

Comment: As for the value of the equity, private companies that offer stock options must file a 409a every 12 months. That is essentially an appraisal of the company, which determines the value of equity for tax purposes.

Comment: @perimpossible Is there ever any *income* involved, or just a capital gain (or loss) upon sale?

Answer (score 1):

The book value of a company is approximately the shareholder's equity from the balance sheet.